# Headphones not recognized

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, thinkpad, headphones, audio-jack

**Before marking as duplicate, please note:** I am aware of the fact that there are several similar issues around here, but the solutions provided there don't seem to work

I have here a Lenovo ThinkPad E555 with a Conexant CX20751/2 sound chip.  Sound generally works, but when I plug headphones in, they are not recognised at all.  (Microphone works, though.)

I have tried to add the following to the alsa-base.conf as recommended so often, but it didn't work:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad
```

I also tried `model=ideapad`, but that didn't work either.

Thank you so much in advance for all hints.

Answer (score 5):

I have experienced the exact same problem and spent hours trying to fix this. For me, the following worked:

- Install `alsa-tools` and `alsa-tools-gui`, you are looking for a program named `hdajackretask`.
- Fire `hdajackretask` up as root.
- Choose `Conexant cx20751/2` in the codec field.
- Click on "show unconnected pins", a pin with the id 0x18 should show up with the remark that it is not connected.
- Click on override and choose headphones in the drop down menu.
- Click on apply now. If you get

  > /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig: Device or resource busy

  [look into this thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/) and search for device or resource busy and do what he tells you to.
- If it worked, a field in alsamixer shows up with the name "auto mute".
- Check that it is enabled and you're good to go.

Unfortunately I do not know if this works with pulseaudio, but I think it's worth a try. You can make it permanent with clicking on "install boot override".

Comment: Regrettably the user of this device gave up as I could not help her with the Ubuntu installation (there where several other problems too) and she is using Windows 7 now. :(

Comment: As commented by @colidyre: "it can also work after restarting computer after overwriting headphones connection if Device or resource busy came up without doing something else (you should give it a try). And also installing alsa-tools-gui for hdajackretask is maybe what you want.

Btw: I had this problem with ElementaryOS (Freya 0.3.1), Ubuntu (14.04.3 LTS) and Linux Mint (17.2 Rafaela) with my Laptop (Thinkpad E555)."

Comment: Your solution with hdajackeretask worked but it is part of the package "alsa-tools-gui" on Ubuntu 14.x. 

It was not connexant for me but codec Realtek ALC3228 on, chipset Azlia 00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01).

I got the device busy as mentioned, so I have clicked on "install boot override" button and "apply now" button (dunno if it was requred), 
Then after a reboot it worked as expected. 

Many thanks!  audio driver tweaking is pure madness :/

Comment: @Phil2.0 I have the very same audio controller and for me it has not configured the headphone properly (only shows it as a headphone in the UI). More details about my issue [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/828046/cant-get-headphones-recognized-on-rear-panel)

Comment: This probably is a solution to my problem on the ThinkPad S440 with Ubuntu 16.04-64, where a certain pair of headphones (Marshall Major II) is not recognized. However I'm not able to select 'headphones' in the dropdown-menu, there's no option for that. Any solution for this?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my Dell laptop, and although this is a Lenovo specific thread, these threads might help - https://askubuntu.com/questions/768463/laptop-headphone-jack-produces-no-sound ;  https://askubuntu.com/questions/219342/no-sound-output-from-headphone-jack-ubuntu12-04/859931 . Doing "alsactl restore" solved the problem for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Same model: updated BIOS from HTET35WW (1.07) to HTET51WW (1.23) and it finally worked!

Grub/Debian example procedure (please, do not follow blindly):

```
sudo apt-get install grub-imageboot
sudo mkdir -p /boot/images
sudo wget -P /boot/images https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/htuj51wd.iso
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot and boot the new `htuj51wd.iso` GRUB entry, then follow the procedure

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/754643)

Comment: @ByteCommander I think it is. The answer reveals that the problem is in firmware of the motherboard, and there is a BIOS release that fixes the problem.

Comment: @ByteCommander When an answer doesn't give as much information as it should, or does not explain itself well enough, [that doesn't mean it should be a comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281/22949). I recommend only advising newcomers that they should've posted a comment when it wouldn't be *wrong* for them to have done so. See "When should I comment?" on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment). (Even when voting to delete from review, if no automatic comment is appropriate, [you can go with the default option of not posting one](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/4219).)