# On Ubuntu 18.04, internal speakers work while headphones have no output

Tags: 18.04, sound, headphones

I have a Dell Inspiron 14 3000 Series. I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 dual booted with Windows 10.

The output of the speakers and headphones work just fine when booted to Windows 10, but when I boot into Ubuntu, the output of the speaker works while the headphones do not.

Pavucontrol shows sound from Rythmbox and that the headphone output is at 100%. I assume this means the headphones are being detected.

The headphones *do* work with other devices.

This question was asked more than one times before me on this site.

Comment: I think this answer may help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/884528/912941

Comment: yes is that same but it solve by  only one comand line

Comment: that is $ alsactl restore