# No sounds from headphone jack Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, realtek

I am running Kubuntu 16.04.1 on a machine with a Realtek ALC898 audio card.

My system can now normally detect the card and play sounds via the speaker however the headphone is not working. I have gone through [No sound output from headphone jack Ubuntu12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219342/no-sound-output-from-headphone-jack-ubuntu12-04?rq=1) and tried the solutions introduced but no luck.

Here are some debug info...

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC898 Analog [ALC898 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC898 Digital [ALC898 Digital]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ lspci | grep audio -i
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)

$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          36864  4
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  19 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

I have also tried `alsamixer` to ensure that the headphone is not muted, and installed `pavucontrol` to check the configurations. I can even see the current volume bar pulsing while playing audio.
[image: pavucontrol snapshot]

I'm using an MSI [GT72S](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/gt72s-6qe-dominator-pro-g.html) laptop and I have this issue when the Nvidia VGA card is enabled.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Well,this counld be an harware problem.Does your laptop detects headphone?

Try this :-

Open the terminal and enter the following commands:

cd /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/
sudo cp analog-output-headphones.conf analog-output-headphones.bak
sudo nano analog-output-headphones.conf

Look for the section called [Element Speaker] and change it so that it looks like this:

[Element Speaker]
switch = on
volume = ignore

Save the changes and exit nano.

Create a backup of the corrected analog-output-headphones.conf:

sudo cp analog-output-headphones.conf analog-output-headphones.fixed

Now you can restore the fix if a future installation or update overwrites it.

Reboot.

After rebooting, you may need to remove and reinsert the headphone plug to get it to work. After it's working, though, you will be able to remove and insert the plug, and behavior will be as expected.

Comment: Yes it does. It even automatically changed the audio configuration for me.

Comment: Not working.... (btw could u plz remove the dupe answer?)

Comment: try pulseaudio @FrederickZhang

Comment: it's already working `E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.`